# FLUTTER + GETX: The children of `MultiChildRenderObjectElement` must each has an associated render object

Tags: flutter, runtime-error, flutter-getx

I've some code managed with the get package. I'm using GetX widget to display a loading indicator during async operations. Everything works, but in console I see this error logged and I don't understand what the problem is.

```dart
return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: GetBuilder<FormController>(
          builder: (cValues) => IconButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Timer(
                const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                cValues.unpick,
              );
              Get.back();
            },
            icon: const Icon(
              Icons.arrow_back,
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text(
          'EDIT MODE',
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 28.75,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            color: const Color(0xff707070),
          ),
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        elevation: 0,
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: [
/* VARIOUS LAYOUT WIDGETS HERE */
          if (!KeyboardVisibilityProvider.isKeyboardVisible(context))
            ColoredButton(
              alignment: const Alignment(0, 0.9),
              text: 'SAVE',
              onTap: () => _validateAndSubmit(context),
              color: AppColors.red,
            ),
          GetX<FormController>( <== ERROR IS GIVEN AT THIS LINE
            builder: (cValues) => cValues.isFetching.isTrue
                ? CustomLoader(text: cValues.currentOperation.value)
                : nil,
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Comment: yeah, ok, interesting, but actually it doesn't reply to my question. I'm fine with GetX. I am doing something wrong and the solution cannot be "throw your work away", do you agree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `nil` with `Container()` and try again.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).